# How to set up a regular expression validating latitude and longitude in a React Native and Expo app

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate the input of two fields in a form, latitude and longitude. Once the input updates it calls a function that first tests the value against a regular expression before calling an action which then updates state via the reducer. When I test the application via the Expo client on my iPhone it accepts numerical inputs but not any of the special characters, i.e. "+", "-" or "."

My first approach was to use /regex/.test(str) and checking whether the result is true or false before proceeding. When this method failed I tried using str.match(/regex/) instead and logged it to the console. The resultant array returns matches for numerical values between 0 and 90 as expected, but as soon as you enter a "+", "-" or "." the array returns a null result.

The function I use for validating latitude values are as follows:

```
   latitudeValidation = (value) => {
      const str = value.toString();
      const regExp = /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)$/;
      const matches = str.match(regExp);
      console.log(matches);
      if (regExp.test(str) || value === '') {
         this.props.updateProp({ prop: 'latitude', value });
      }
   }
```

For longitudes the regular expression I use is:

```
   const regExp = /^[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/;
```

The idea behind the validation is to limit user input to the range of latitude values [-90.0, +90.0] and longitude values [-180, +180]. Entering numerical values work as expected, but the special characters are the problem. Here's the output of the matches array when I try to enter 89.0:

```
   Array [
      "8",
      "8",
      undefined,
      undefined,
   ]

   Array [
      "89",
      "89",
      undefined,
      undefined,
   ]

   null
```

Comment: I think `value.toString()` loses the decimal part.You might take a look at [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) perhaps

Comment: Does it have to be a regexp?

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for the input, this was however a classic example of me truly missing the essence of the problem at hand. I was trying to run that validation on every keystroke instead of when the final value is submitted.

Comment: @SalmanA I guess it does not have to be. I wanted to force the user to only enter a proper latitude or longitude upon entry. With regex this becomes quite tricky. I resorted to validating upon submission and only allowing "+","-","." and numerical values in the field itself. If you have a way to force users to only enter proper latitudes and longitudes before they submit the values I am all ears.

Comment: `var val = Number(value); return Number.isNaN(val) === false && val >= -180 && val <= 180`

Comment: @SalmanA this could work, thanks.

Comment: Your question is purely javascript, nothing to do with expo or react-native

Comment: @Fakebounce the reason I tagged them was to give context. I have removed them however to prevent others from commenting the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with the regular expression itself, but with the implementation of the validation. The regular expression worked as intended, but because the function fired on every keystroke the value of the field is tested against the full complement of the regular expression. Thus by entering a "-" the expression fails because it expects not only a "-", but also a numerical value between 0 and 90. Also, entering 89 will work because it doesn't break the rule, however trying to add a decimal point will fail because the regular expression will not allow a value of 89. it requires numerical characters after the decimal point.

The solution to the problem at hand is thus to allow the user to enter only certain characters by using the regular expression /^[-+0-9.]+$/ instead, and then when the user finally submits the value to check it against the original regular expression.

The original function thus becomes:

```
   latitudeEntry = (value) => {
      const regExp = /^[-+0-9.]+$/;
      if (regExp.test(value) || value === '') {
         this.props.updateProp({ prop: 'latitude', value });
      }
   }
```

And a separate validation function when submitting the value:

```
   latitudeValidation = (value) => {
      const regExp = /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)$/;
      if (regExp.test(value)) {
         // Do database entry here via action...
         // something like: this.props.addLatitude({ latitude: value });
      }
   }
```

@SalmanA made a good suggestion in the comments to improve checks on the input which I will also implement.